# Reuse an image resp. a box in TikZ but have side-effects only once

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, warnings, labels, tikz-external

I have a huge document (a pool of exercise problems) with lots of `\input` statements (one file per subexercise). In order to not get lost in this mess and easily open files from the PDF, I include a margin note with a link to the included file at every `\input` and `\includegraphics`.

Now I started seeing warnings like

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `note.1.1' multiply defined.
```

I narrowed the issue down to this MFE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/mode=list and make,%
         external/export=true}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\inclimage}[2][]{%
  \marginnote{\texttt{#2}}\includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
  \def\icon{\inclimage[width=100pt]{example-image.png}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\icon};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\icon};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

<sup>The document needs two runs to translate, and compilation of the externalized pictures in between. I'm reasonably certain that `list and make` is not relevant to the problem, but that's how I use it.</sup>

Now, in the aux file I find:

```
\def \dpthimport {\newmarginnote {note.1.1}{{\themn@abspage }{0sp}}}\dpthimport
```

Remove either TikZ externalization or the margin note business, the warnings vanish. In fact, without externalization the aux file contains only

```
\newmarginnote{note.1.1}{{2}{10000988sp}}
```

The use of `\dpthimport` seems to be related to externalization.

So, the problem seems to be that when translating each picture for itself (due to externalisation), `marginnote` picks the same label name for each instance of `\icon` which then conflict when the whole document is compiled (again).

I tried to define the image once and reuse it inside the pictures.

- With save boxes:

  ```
  \begin{document}
    \newsavebox{\IconBox}
    \sbox{\IconBox}{\tikz\node{\inclimage[width=100pt]{example-image.png}};}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node {\usebox{\IconBox}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node {\usebox{\IconBox}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

  Same warning, two margin notes (with weird positions).
- With `pic` from TikZ 3.0:

  ```
  \begin{document}
    \tikzset{%
      icon/.pic={\node {\inclimage[width=100pt]{example-image.png}};}
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pic {icon};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \pic {icon};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

  Same warning, no margin note.

How can I define an image resp. a box in such a way that

- it is expanded only once, i.e. side-effects (such as margin notes) apply only once, and
- it can be reused in a TikZ image?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\inclimage}[2][]{%
  \marginnote{\texttt{#2}}\includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
  \newsavebox{\IconBox}
  \sbox{\IconBox}{\tikz\node{\inclimage[width=100pt]{example-image.png}};}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\usebox{\IconBox}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\usebox{\IconBox}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

As the box has a `\write` note that gets used twice. `\leaders` is a TeX primitive intended to repeat a box multiple times, usually for `......` in tables of contents etc, but you can arrange the leaders to only make one copy, as a useful side effect of wrapping a box in leaders is that all writes are disabled.

So

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\inclimage}[2][]{%
  \marginnote{\texttt{#2}}\includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
}

\def\xusebox#1{\leavevmode\leaders\copy#1\hskip\wd#1\\kern0pt\relax}
\begin{document}
  \newsavebox{\IconBox}
  \sbox{\IconBox}{\tikz\node{\inclimage[width=100pt]{example-image.png}};}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\xusebox{\IconBox}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\xusebox{\IconBox}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces no warning (it takes two runs to get rid of the effects of the aux file if you edit the document).

Using `\leaders` in this way is generally applicable although in this case the layout is rather strange as marginal notes can not do anything inside a `\sbox` (which is a horizontal construct with no linebreaking or margins).